# Assigning text of controls from Resources in VS form desinger

Tags: c#

I have my strings present in a manually created resx file.
I am creating a new C# Windows Form in my app. In the form I create multiple labels controls. 
I want to point the text of the controls to be set from resources, rather than hard coding them in the properties panel.

Is there a way to have designer generated code refer to strings from my resources ?

I have quite a few forms to be created with VS form desinger and want the strings to go from resources.

Please advise, 
thanks,

Comment: It is built into the designer.  Set the form's Localizable property to True.  Change the Language and edit the Text properties.  You'll get satellite assemblies with the language specific resources after you build.

Comment: I have my different versions of strings Strings.es , Strings.fr etc When I create localized forms, I want to set the text of my controls on localized Form from my Strings.xx resx files rather than explicitly provide Text for my controls in the desinger

Comment: Inventing your own localization scheme is very unwise, given that the built-in one works so well and is supported by any localization shop.  If you want to do it your way then go ahead, just don't expect anybody to help you do it.

Comment: I am not inventing my own, I just want one resource file for each language rather than ending up with two resource files per language. One created by the designer and one manually created to use text in dilogs and other dynamic controls..

Answer (score 0):

```
//Name Spaces Required

using System.Resources;
using System.Reflection;

// Create the resource manager.
 Assembly assembly = this.GetType().Assembly;

//ResFile.Strings -> <Namespace>.<ResourceFileName i.e. Strings.resx> 
resman = new ResourceManager("StringResources.Strings", assembly);

// Load the value of string value for Client
strClientName = resman.GetString("IDS_MESSAGE");
```